# WOWZA: How to connect live edge repeater to another live edge repeater?

Tags: wowza

I have setup live origin wowza instance and live edge (edge1) and that is working fine. I need to setup now another live edge instance (edge2) to fetch streams from edge1. So everything to be connected as following:

origin <-- edge1 <-- edge2 <--client

So when a client connect to edge2 it will initiate connection to edge1 and edge1 will pull stream from origin.

How to achieve above scenario? It is important to connection be on demand and not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you've set up origin and edge applications, so the Primary Origin URL for the edge should be pointing to the origin.

Now, you can create a second edge application where the Primary Origin URL refers to the original edge application.

When you playback via the Test Player on the second edge application (or look at the Incoming Streams page), you'll see that it's pulling from the original edge application.